# Make simple substraction in PostGIS with Map Algebra operation

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, qgis

I have multiple raster images in my PostGIS database, and created tiles of each raster. Now I want to subtract the values of one raster from a second raster image and I want to save the changed values in a third raster image. On postgis.net are some examples but they weren't so helpful for my specific question. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some useres, who have the same problem I got the answer. Following command calculaes the diffrence between two rasters, that are saved in separate table in postGIS:

```
SELECT ST_MapAlgebra(t1.rast,t2.rast, '([rast1]-[rast2])') AS rast INTO diffrence FROM table1 t1, table2 t2;
```